# Server ONLY connects via TLS 1.0

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a server running Windows Server 2012 R2. It has TLS 1.2, 1.1, and 1.0 configured. However, when making outgoing/remote connections it *only* seems to want to connect to other servers via TLS 1.0. If the external server supports TLS 1.1 & 1.2, but NOT TLS 1.0, then the connection is closed.

Why won't the system establish connections with third-party servers when both support TLS 1.1+?

Comment: Try connecting to the servers with a client that will give you more details on the connection, such as `openssl s_client`, to verify that you really can connect with a higher version of TLS and you're not getting errors. It could also be useful to capture the negotiation (try Wireshark) and see if the higher versions are being requested or offered. It's possible your client may support 1.1+ but has a setting that's limiting it to 1.0.

Comment: What client are you using to initiate the connections? ASP.NET? A web browser? Local client application? Which version of the client app are you using? Details like these are important if you want an answer.